# Why is Ignite redux persist throwing immutable error when adding navigation reducer to whitelist?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, redux-persist

I am using react native Ignite Andross Boilerplate and I am trying to persist the navigation state so that when the user close/open the app it will come back to the previous screen.

For exemple: The user is filling a sign up form then closes the app and cames back later to finish wherever he stoped.

Since redux persist is given out of the box with Ignite, I tought I could just add the navigation reducer to the persist whitelist and let redux persist to its job saving my nav state on local storage.

So I did this:

```
// App/Config/ReduxPersist.js

import immutablePersistenceTransform from '../Services/ImmutablePersistenceTransform'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

// More info here:  https://shift.infinite.red/shipping-persistant-reducers-7341691232b1
const REDUX_PERSIST = {
  active: true,
  reducerVersion: '1.1',
  storeConfig: {
    key: 'primary',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    // Reducer keys that you do NOT want stored to persistence here.
    blacklist: ['login', 'search'],
    // Optionally, just specify the keys you DO want stored to persistence.
    // An empty array means 'don't store any reducers' -> infinitered/ignite#409
    whitelist: ['nav'],
    transforms: [immutablePersistenceTransform]
  }
}

export default REDUX_PERSIST
```

The thing is...I got this error as result:

[image]

And somehow I realized that the `immutablePersistenceTransform` was the one to blame. How did I know that ? Well...I didn't! I just saw that the only thing immutable related was that transform and I commented it.

So when my code is the following it works:

```
// App/Config/ReduxPersist.js

import immutablePersistenceTransform from '../Services/ImmutablePersistenceTransform'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

// More info here:  https://shift.infinite.red/shipping-persistant-reducers-7341691232b1
const REDUX_PERSIST = {
  active: true,
  reducerVersion: '1.1',
  storeConfig: {
    key: 'primary',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    // Reducer keys that you do NOT want stored to persistence here.
    blacklist: ['login', 'search'],
    // Optionally, just specify the keys you DO want stored to persistence.
    // An empty array means 'don't store any reducers' -> infinitered/ignite#409
    whitelist: ['nav'],
    //transforms: [immutablePersistenceTransform]
  }
}

export default REDUX_PERSIST
```

// App/Services/ImmutablePersistenceTransform.js

Why is this error occuring ? Is commenting the transform the best workaround ? Any help will be welcome!!!

Also, the `immutablePersistenceTransform` is the following:

```
import R from 'ramda'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

// is this object already Immutable?
const isImmutable = R.has('asMutable')

// change this Immutable object into a JS object
const convertToJs = (state) => state.asMutable({deep: true})

// optionally convert this object into a JS object if it is Immutable
const fromImmutable = R.when(isImmutable, convertToJs)

// convert this JS object into an Immutable object
const toImmutable = (raw) => Immutable(raw)

// the transform interface that redux-persist is expecting
export default {
  out: (state) => {
    // console.log({ retrieving: state })
    return toImmutable(state)
  },
  in: (raw) => {
    // console.log({ storing: raw })
    return fromImmutable(raw)
  }
}
```

Any help ?

Answer (score -2):

Man, i think that "nav" is not a Immutable data structure. That is why throw this error